# How to convert (0,0) to [0,0] in prolog?

Tags: string, list, prolog

I'm making a predicate distance/3 that calculates the distance between 2 points on a 2d plane. For example :

```
?- distance((0,0), (3,4), X).
X = 5
Yes
```

My predicate only works if `(0,0)` is the list `[0,0]`. Is there a way to make this conversion?

Comment: Note that `(0,0)` is a more compact and efficient representation than `[0,0]`. That's (more) apparent when you look to the canonical representation of both terms: `','(0,0)` vs `'.'(0,'.'(0,[]))`. I'm curious why your predicate can only work with a list representation...

Comment: Because i use a head tail split to apply the theorem of Pythagoras to (0,0) and (3,4).

Comment: But you don't need to do a head-tail split. You can easily extract the values from `(X,Y)`. `distance((X1,Y1), (X2,Y2), D) :- D is sqrt((X2-X1)*(X2-X1)+(Y2-Y1)*(Y2-Y1)).` You can also define `square(X, S) :- S is X*X.` if you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple rule that *unifies* its left and right sides:

```
convert((A,B), [A,B]).
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/X2qNUV)

Comment: Thanks, i've got it to work now. Although i do have a feeling i can make my program a bit "prettyer". I'll work on that :)

Answer (score 2):

Although the others have answered, keep in mind that `(a,b)` in Prolog is actually not what you might think it is:

```
?- write_canonical((a,b)).
','(a,b)
true.
```

So this is the term `','/2`. If you are working with pairs, you can do two things that are probably "prettier":

Keep them as a "pair", `a-b`:

```
?- write_canonical(a-b).
-(a,b)
true.
```

The advantage here is that pairs like this can be manipulated with a bunch of de-facto standard predicates, for example `keysort`, as well as [library(pairs)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs).

Or, if they are actually a data structure that is part of your program, you might as well make that explicit, as in `coor(a, b)` for example. A distance in two-dimensional space will then take two `coor/2` terms:

```
distance(coor(X1, Y1), coor(X2, Y2), D) :-
    D is sqrt((X1-X2)^2 + (Y1-Y2)^2).
```

If you don't know how many dimensions you have, you can then indeed keep the coordinates of each point in a list. The message here is that lists are meant for things that can have 0 or more elements in them, while pairs, or other terms with arity 2, or any term with a known arity, are more explicit about the number of elements they have.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a simple pair, you can use the `univ` operator and simply say something like:

```
X = (a,b) ,
X =.. [_|Y] .
```

which produces

```
X = (a,b) .
Y = [a,b] .
```

This doesn't work if `X` is something like `(a,b,c)`, producing as it does

```
X = (a,b,c) .
Y = [a,(b,c)] .
```

[probably not what you want].

The more general case is pretty simple:

```
csv2list( X , [X]     ) :- % We have a list of length 1
  var(X) .                 % - if X is UNbound
csv2list( X , [X]     ) :- % We have a list of length 1
  nonvar(X) ,              % - if X is bound, and
  X \= (_,_) .             % - X is not a (_,_) term.
cs22list( Xs , [A|Ys] ) :- % otherwise (the general case) ,
  nonvar(Xs) ,             % - if X is bound, and
  Xs = (A,Bs) ,            % - X is a (_,) term,
  csv2list(Bs,Ys           % - recurse down added the first item to result list.
  .                        % Easy!
```